# Set crontab backup job for Mariadb Databases from 1 remote server to another

Tags: backup, mariadb, ubuntu, cron

I'm connecting to a Ubuntu Server remotely using SSH, where are x number of MariaDB databases.
Now I want to set a crontab job to automatically create backup for all of them to another server where are stored back-ups from differents servers.
How can I do this?

Comment: "How can I do this?" -- by editing the crontab file, I suppose.

Comment: Do you want every database in its own file, or would one database dump per server work?

Comment: I want every database in its own file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your task will not fit into one command.

You need a bash script. If your backup server has FTP then here is a [good script](https://sqlbak.com/blog/how-to-automatically-upload-mysql-backup-to-ftp-on-linux) . If FTP is not installed on the server, and you do not want to bring it up, then you can transfer the file via ssh using `rsync`.

To use `rsync` in a script, you need access ssh via ssh keys. If this is not configured, then it is very simple to do it:

First, generate the key:

```
ssh-keygen
```

*The utility will ask you to enter the file name and passphrase (optional). To leave the default values, just press Enter.*

Then, transfer the public key to the backup server:

```
ssh-copy-id <my-remoute-user>@<my-remoute-host>
```

Note, if something goes wrong, you need to receive a notification. The easiest way is to receive an email. You can do it via postfix mailutils packages. To instal tit, please execute:

```
sudo apt-get install postfix mailutils
```

Well, the script itself. As a basis, I took the script that I recommended above, adding sending a backup via `rsync`.

At the beginning of the script, specify the settings:

```
set -x
# MySQL user
user=ivan
# MySQL password
password=my-secret-password
# Local backup storage directory
local_backupfolder=mysql/backups
# Notification email address
recipient_email=my-email@gmail.com
# Number of days to store the backup
keep_day=30
# remote backup storage
remoute_backupfolder=backup-admin@my-backup-server.com:/home/backup-admin/
sqlfile=$local_backupfolder/all-database-$(date +%d-%m-%Y_%H-%M-%S).sql
#create backup folder
mkdir -p $local_backupfolder

mysqldump -u $user -p$password --all-databases > $sqlfile;

# Create a backup
if gzip $sqlfile; then
   echo 'Backup compressed'
else
   echo 'gzip return non-zero code' | mailx -s 'No backup was created!' $recipient_email
   exit
fi

# Delete old backups
find $local_backupfolder -mtime +$keep_day -delete

# Local and remote storage sync
if rsync -avh --delete $local_backupfolder $remoute_backupfolder ; then
   echo 'Backup sended'
else
   echo 'rsync return non-zero code' | mailx -s 'No backup was sended!' $recipient_email
   exit
fi

echo $sqlfile.gz | mailx -s 'Backup was successfully created' $recipient_email
```

- 

*This "backup script" backups all databases on the server at once. If you need to backup only specific databases, then instead of the --all-database parameter, use the --database parameter specifying the name of the database you want to backup.*